# Return 2 columns using subquerys in main query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I wish to populate a table on in a mysql database. Firstly I'd like to pull back all of the possibilities and them trim out the unrequired ones (easier than just adding them by hand).

The final table is:

### combinations

```
combID
productID
type
content
exclude
extrafield2
extrafield6
```

The data comes from

### extrafields_values

```
exvalueID
productID
extrafieldID
content
```

For each product I need to get return a row for each combination in extra_field_values (extrafieldID = 2 and extrafieldID = 6)

For instance:

- productID = 700
- extrafield2 = E, D, F
- extrafield6 = 34,35,36,37

Returns the exvalueID to extrafields2 and 6 for each combination

So far I've tried:

```
SELECT EV.productID, extraFieldID, content AS extrafield6, 
    (SELECT  content AS extrafield2 
     FROM wjf_extrafields_values AS EV2
         INNER JOIN wjf_products AS P2
     WHERE extraFieldID = 6) AS extrafield2 
FROM wjf_extrafields_values AS EV 
    INNER JOIN wjf_products AS P ON P.productID = EV.productID 
WHERE extrafieldID = 6
```

Comment: Why am I asking a ~1500 rep account to post what they've tried?!

Comment: Because you care Ponies. Because you care. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to link your `wjf_products` table to your `extrafield_values` table twice as shown below.

```
select p.productID, ev1.content as extrafield2, ev2.content as extrafield6
from wjf_products p inner join extrafields_values ev1 on p.productID = ev1.productID
inner join extrafields_values ev2 on p.productID = ev2.productID
where ev1.extraFieldID = 2
and ev2.extraFieldID = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create and use two views instead of a query.

View1 = Combinations

View2 = Subset of View1

Insert data using the View2